# Fragment to Fragment Transition: postponeEnterTransition() does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition, fragment-transitions

I am using Android X transitions to animate content with motion between two Fragments, within the same hosting Activity.

I am trying to animate an ImageView which Image is loaded with Glide and an URL.

The problem I have is, regardless of the two ImageViews sizes, their size is 0 before the image is loaded, **and because of that, the transitions capture wrong layout values and therefore show a shrinking animation** (animating to size 0).

I have read about using `postponeEnterTransition()` which should, in association with `startPostponedEnterTransition()` delay the transition for the duration between the two calls.

This is the schema:

- Fragment A, image is at the bottom of the screen, width is that of half of the screen's width.
- Fragment B, image is at the top of the screen, width is that of the screen's width.

On Fragment A's image click, the Fragment B is loaded.

In Fragment B's `onCreate` I set my transitions using `setSharedElementEnterTransition(transitions)`. Then I immediately call `postponeEnterTransition()`;

In Fragment B's `onCreateView`, I await for the ImageView to be pre-drawn (using the ViewTreeObserver), after layout inflation, and then I call `startPostponedEnterTransition()`.

Using a breakpoint and a listener on my transitions, the listener#onTransitionStarted is triggered before I reach the pre-draw callback, which proves the transition captured wrong layout values.

Also, another proof that `postponeEnterTransition()` has no effect whatsoever, removing the call to `startPostponedEnterTransition()` does not hold the transition forever.

What am I doing wrong ?
And of course, when returning to Fragment A, the same shrinking animation is being played out as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set reordering allowed during your fragment transaction by adding `setReorderingAllowed(true)` to your transaction.

See [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setReorderingAllowed(boolean)) and the Reordering part of [this blog post by Chris Banes](https://chris.banes.dev/2018/02/18/fragmented-transitions/) for more context.

Comment: How could I haved misse that out ? Thanks. I cannot test as I have moved on to not do transitions (projects requirement), but I'll validate your answer anyway because if this does not work, what will make it work ? Thanks and cheers !

Comment: Unfortunately, setReorderingAllowed(true) breaks my back animation (return animation to the calling fragment). Any idea why that is?